# Automatically download external packages

Tags: init-file, package, config

How can I configure my init.el download packages that are not in (M)Elpa and install them automatically (if not already installed)?

Something like doing it with wget or with git (as you do in vim) and then install them:

```
wget http://www.web.com/script.el
git clone https://github.com/user/package.git
```

And then install it with `M-x package-install-file`. Or something like that.
I don't know anything about lisp and I would like to do that from my init.el

Comment: You may find the answer to your request, following this [link](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get#advanced-usage-with-local-recipes)